# Get rid of read more link in news Teaser

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, tx-news

I have a news list element on my site with no detail page associated with it. But the Teaser headline and image are still links and the `read more` links is still displayed.

How do I disable all links to the detail page in the Teaser.

I searched for dokumentation on this but all I could find dealt with the `tt_news` extention and not `tx-news`.

Comment: Are you sure `news` is not the same as `tt_news`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [edit the templates](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/Start/Index.html) and remove the links from the list view.

You'll find this template in /ext/news/Resources/Private/Partials/List/Item.html

Don't edit this original file, but copy it like explained in the link above.

Now change for example ...

```
<h3>
    <n:link newsItem="{newsItem}" settings="{settings}" title="{newsItem.title}">
        <span itemprop="headline">{newsItem.title}</span>
    </n:link>
</h3>
```

...to ...

```
<h3>
        <span itemprop="headline">{newsItem.title}</span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in Italian but appears to address your problem.

> in typoscript plugin configuration:
>
> ```
> {plugin.tx_news 
>     {_LOCAL_LANG 
>         default { 
>             read_more = read 
>         } 
>         it { 
>             read_more = VEC 
>         } 
> .... other languages ​​.... 
>     } 
> }
> ```

via http://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/195490/